# How to push only new records in a local MongoDB to another remote instance?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a local collection which is hosted on an offline MongoDB instance; with offline I mean not always connected to the Internet.
And another remote one which acts like 'universal' collection for these multiple 'not always connected MongoDBs'

What I want to do is, when the offline instance becomes online all new records should be pushed to that central DB, knowing that I only need to push records, not updating the deleted ones or any of that.

Internet connectivity check is easy to implement, though it would be useful if Mongo implements it already.

I found this solution [here](https://sheharyar.me/blog/sync-mongodb-local-and-production-heroku/). But it does synchronization. I'm new to this technology, so pardon me if it seems basic scenario.

I'm using Python.

Comment: if you were using mongoDB as replica set then mongo-connector is another solution for synchronization.

Comment: The thing is I don't want synchronization, if I got it right, synchronization is 2 way. while I only want to push records from 'part' to 'whole'.

Comment: you can use queriable mogodump to dump only those records which are added after last sync. same can be restored using mongorestore

Comment: @Astro I googled the tools you mentioned, and thanks to you I can start to look from there. If you would like to post this comment as an answer, I would be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use queryable [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-query) to dump only those records which are added after last sync.

Same dump can be restored using mongorestore.